# Sorting or finding a images based on their dimensions

Tags: macos, images, finder

I ran this file recovery tool to see if I could find a previously deleted image and the results were rather impressive. It recovered a little over 150,000 images (40GB total).

If I go image by image I won't be done with this for a few weeks, and I'm just wondering if there's an automated way to go through such a large set. I've tried several apps, all which have crashed. I know the exact image dimension, but Finder doesn't return any results since it hasn't indexed the images.

I would like to sort the files by image dimension or search by the exact dimension.

Comment: Sort by image dimension only would be helpful. Or any solution that doesn't crash would be great, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to run a Spotlight search, if your recovered image files are already Spotlight indexed:

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop "kMDItemPixelWidth == 123 && kMDItemPixelHeight == 456"
```

Here, you can specify the folder to search in (e.g. `~/Desktop`) as well as the specific width and height values associated to the image you want to find.

The command should return a list of paths to the files that match the search criteria.

For more info, see: [Digging Deeper: Mastering Spotlight in OS X - Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/03/digging-deeper-mastering-spotlight-in-os-x/)